# Step not found in progress tracker even though it's defined

Tags: corda

I'm getting the following error when I run my flow:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Step Requesting Stellar to execute the escrow. not found in progress tracker.
    at net.corda.core.utilities.ProgressTracker.setCurrentStep(ProgressTracker.kt:140) ~[corda-core-4.3.jar:?]
    at com.finablr.money.loyalty.wallet.flows.RevokeCustomToken.call(RevokeCustomToken.java:139) ~[wallet-workflows-0.1.jar:?]
    at com.finablr.money.loyalty.wallet.flows.RevokeCustomToken.call(RevokeCustomToken.java:36) ~[wallet-workflows-0.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:270) ~[corda-node-4.3.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:46) ~[corda-node-4.3.jar:?]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.run1(Fiber.java:1092) ~[quasar-core-0.7.10-jdk8.jar:0.7.10]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.exec(Fiber.java:788) ~[quasar-core-0.7.10-jdk8.jar:0.7.10]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.doExec(RunnableFiberTask.java:100) ~[quasar-core-0.7.10-jdk8.jar:0.7.10]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.run(RunnableFiberTask.java:91) ~[quasar-core-0.7.10-jdk8.jar:0.7.10]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at net.corda.node.utilities.AffinityExecutor$ServiceAffinityExecutor$1$thread$1.run(AffinityExecutor.kt:63) ~[corda-node-4.3.jar:?]
```

Even though I do have that step defined inside my flow:

```
private final Step STELLAR_EXECUTE_ESCROW = new Step("Requesting Stellar to execute the escrow.");

private final ProgressTracker progressTracker = new ProgressTracker(    
    STELLAR_EXECUTE_ESCROW
);

// Inside the call() method.
// Checkpoint workflow to replay from here in case of node failure.
sleep(Duration.ofMillis(1));

// Request Stellar to execute the escrow.
progressTracker.setCurrentStep(STELLAR_EXECUTE_ESCROW);
```

Flow tests didn't throw that error, it only happened on Google cloud; not sure whether check-pointing the flow is causing that or not.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying the issue was unique to google cloud? You didn't have this issue when running locally?

I'd double-check how you've defined the progressTracker.

Here's the highlights on a progresstracker definition from a code sample I've got handy.

```
public class YoFlow extends FlowLogic<SignedTransaction> {
    private static final ProgressTracker.Step CREATING = new ProgressTracker.Step("Creating a new Yo!");
    private static final ProgressTracker.Step SIGNING = new ProgressTracker.Step("Signing the Yo!");
    private static final ProgressTracker.Step VERIFYING = new ProgressTracker.Step("Verfiying the Yo!");
    private static final ProgressTracker.Step FINALISING = new ProgressTracker.Step("Sending the Yo!") {
        @Nullable
        @Override
        public ProgressTracker childProgressTracker() {
            return FinalityFlow.tracker();
        }
    };

    ProgressTracker progressTracker = new ProgressTracker(
            CREATING,
            SIGNING,
            VERIFYING,
            FINALISING
    );

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public ProgressTracker getProgressTracker() {
        return progressTracker;
    }

    private final Party target;

    public YoFlow(Party target) {
        this.target = target;
    }

    @Suspendable
    @Override
    public SignedTransaction call() throws FlowException {
        progressTracker.setCurrentStep(CREATING);
```

As another possibility, make sure you're overriding the progress tracker methods, if you don't then you can't call the flow over SSH due to an obscure corda bug.

See https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.4/shell.html#limitations

> "Flows cannot be run unless they override the progress tracker"